# How does this typedef works?

Tags: c, typedef

I saw this line of code and I do not understand what is typedef:ed where...

```
typedef void *(*SomeType)(OtherType mem, thirdtype size);
```

So, how do I use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typedef of a function pointer.

```
typedef void *(*SomeType)(OtherType mem, thirdtype size);

void* func (OtherType mem, thirdtype size) {}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
SomeType fptr = &func;

fptr(someMem, someSize);
```

Or can itself be passed as a parameter to a function

```
void memory_visitor (SomeType visit_cb)
{
  ...
  if (visit_cb)
    visit_cb (visistedMem, visistedMemSize);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a web site for that: [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/), aka [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)

To the question: `void *(*SomeType)(OtherType, thirdtype)`,

its answer is:

> declare SomeType as pointer to function (OtherType, thirdtype)
>   returning pointer to void

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is a great way for learning C declaration system.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeType` is a pointer to function which accepts `OtherType` and `thirdtype` as arguments and returns `void *`

Answer (score 0):

Found this useful link once when i was facing the problem in reading complex c declarations.
Might help you.

[How to read complex C deaclaration](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)